# Sending JavaScript Variable to PHP via POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

Is it possible to send the contents of a JavaScript variable to PHP when a form is submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
Just add a javascript callback to the form submit event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myglobalvariable = "myvalue";
    onSubmit = function(){
        document.myform.myinput.value = myglobalvariable;  return true;
    }
</script>
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="onSubmit();">
    <input name="myinput" id="myinput" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much! :)

How would I access the retrieved data, though? `$_POST['myinput']` doesn't seem to be it :P I can't var_dump on this server.

Comment: The array key is the name of the input in question. In my example, it'll be 'myinput' but your code doesn't show name attributes on inputs. You should add them to retrieve the values from the $_POST supergrobal

Comment: Gah, I made a typo haha. That's why it wasn't working. Thanks very much once again :)